# Why are certain hashes missing from the .git objects folder?

Tags: vulnerability, git

I'm currently attempting to pentest a web application created by a relation, who wanted me to find vulnerabilities and to let him know what exploits would be possible with said vulnerabilities.

I have discovered the .git folder is publicly exposed, albeit with directory indexing turned off. I attempted to scrape the .git folder, but a lot of the found commit hashes in the logs do not exist in the .git/objects directory. Therefore, only a part of the original source code has been fetched.

This made me wonder, why are certain SHA1-hashes missing from the objects folder? I read something about Git using .pack files to compress stuff. How would one find out the hashes of the .pack files, to get the rest of the source code as well?

Comment: There is an `.idx` file for each packfile that lets you quickly find out whether that packfile contains an object, but I don't think there is a file that lists all packfiles. After all, you are usually able to list directories when working with a Git repository